# What should I store as my index in client code?

Tags: mysql, database, google-app-engine

I'm using Google App Engine and storing users. Before, I was using MySQL with an auto-incrementing int for my userId field, but now GAE auto generates a key for each new entity I store, such as `g5kZXZ-aGVsbG93b3JsZHIKCxIEVXNlchgNDA`, but they also automatically generate an auto-incrementing ID int too.

Which one should I use in my client code to store as the userId? Are there any advantages to using the long key that GAE generates, or is using the small int ID the same thing in terms of performance and look ups? Are there any advantages to one over the other, or is there practically no difference?

**Edit:** Sorry my question was not clear enough. Here's what I'm asking:
It's not about length, but does having the lookup key put me a step ahead of not having it? Because if I wanted to look up a user, I'd have to look him up by email, but now that I have the key for that row in the "table", does this give me any sort of advantage?

Comment: Are you talking about using [OpenID](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID) or something else?  I'd find out what the long term plan is for both and how both are to be used via their documentation.  Pick the one that seems like it will be around the longest and unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either one is fine, there's no performance difference between using a long string of letters or a short one to identify users.

Comment: Well it's not about length, but if does having the key put me a step ahead of not having it? Because if I wanted to look up a user, I'd have to look him up by email, but now that I have the key for that row in the "table", does this give me any sort of advantage?

Comment: You'll probably want to look up by the key, as the datastore's API is optimized for this. Maintaining an autoincrementing ID is also inefficient in high-performance scenarios, so you may want to investigate removing it.

Comment: Ok great. So how can I quickly fetch by key if I already have it? Currently I'm doing `users=User.all()
  users.filter("userEmail =", userEmail)
  user=users.get()`
Is it just through another filter?

Comment: If you have a key you can just call `db.get(key)` https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/functions#get -- no queries required, and it accepts multiple keys to fetch multiple entities.

Comment: Ok and one last thing while I have you here: http://i.imgur.com/6tfVY.png The first 4 columns are generated by the system. What does Key Name represent? And does getting rid of the field ID (not sure if that's possible) decrease the number of write ops?

Comment: You can specify a string key name for a model class, e.g., `MyModel(key_name='bob').put()` and `MyModel.get_by_key_name('bob')`. The ID field is generated by the system and you won't be able to remove it -- read more about these at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities and https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass

Comment: How can I access the ID field if I have a user? can I do user.ID() like I do user.key()?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10084/discussion-between-jason-hall-and-mohabitar)

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the generated entity ID is not guaranteed to be a monotonically increasing value.