# AppEngine id/key/from_path is quite confusing what should I use

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I am back into AppEngine development.
And I am quite hang up with the Datastorage.

I am used to "ids", building the website with links like "/view?id=322345" gets me the GuestBook entry with this id voilà.

But in AppEngine I always see the db.Key.from_path() method called and other stuff like "Ancestors" and "parents".

In my project I have simple relationships like User->Phonenumbers, and I want to inspect each User via a GET url appending something id-like.
Should I use the User models key() or how is this in AppEngine achieved?

Currently if I want to add i.e. a PhoneNumber to the User I write the following:

```
class JoinHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        user_key = self.request.get('rlm')
        fon_number = PhoneNumber()
        fon_number.country = "deDE"
        fon_number.user = db.Key(user_key)
        fon_number.put()
        self.redirect("/")
```

Comment: similar to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10156129/what-should-i-store-as-my-index-in-client-code

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using the numeric ids that are automatically assigned by the datastore when you `put` an entity, you can then retrieve the entity with the model's `get_by_id` method:

```
class User(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    # etc.

def AddUser(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        newUser = User()
        newUser.name = self.request.get('name')
        # etc. assign all model properties
        newUser.put()
        # now, newUser.Key().id() contains the auto-assigned numeric id.
        # we can pass this value to our template and get it back via
        # a form paramter for subsequent operations.

def ShowUser(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        user_to_show_id = self.request.get('id')
        user_to_show = User.get_by_id(user_to_show_id)
        if user_to_show is not None:
            # populate the template parameters with the users's data
            # and render the template
        else:
            # The requested user does not exist, so
            # render an error message/page.
```

Now, if you also want to store phone number entities that belong to a given user, you make store them such that their parent is the User entity. This puts them in the User's entity group and entities that are in an entity group can be queried together more quickly than if they are stored with parents.

Let's say that any User can have any given number of Phonenumber entities associated with it:

```
class Phonenumber(db.Model):
    number_type = db.StringProperty()
    number = db.StringProperty()
```

We'll add a method to the User class:

```
def AddNumber(self, new_number_type, new_number):
    new_number = Phonenumber(parent=self, number_type=new_number_type, number=new_number)
    # In this case, self is the User entity, and by saying parent=self, we're putting
    # this Phonenumber entity into User's entity group.
    new_number.put()

def GetPhoneNumber(self):
    # Now, getting all of User's phone numbers is a simple as a query with an
    # Ancestor clause:
    users_numbers = Phonenumber.all().ancestor(self).fetch(1000)

   return users_numbers
```

Obviously, these classes are naive and straight off the top of my head, but I hope that they'll help you understand both id's and ancestor relationships. Often times, you won't have to use `Key()` to manually create keys at all. Don't go that route unless you really need to. Still, understanding how Keys work is good for really understanding AppEngine, so dive in and experiment if you feel like it.

I think that those were your two main questions, yeah? If you have others, go ahead and leave a comment, and I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Don't you have to cast user_to_show_id into an int? It does not work for me if I don't cast it...

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering if I was doing something wrong. I am new to this.

Answer (score 2):

As far as your question about what `db.Key.from_path()` will do, check the [Key Class docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keyclass#Key_from_path) and you'll see that the first argument to `from_path()` is the **kind** of datastore object you're going to be retrieving.

Args are listed as such:

`Key.from_path(kind, id_or_name, parent=None, namespace=None)`

In one of my basic blog apps I have the following line:

`key = db.Key.from_path('BlogPost', int(post_id), parent=blog_key())`

This is looking for an object of type `BlogPost`, with an id of `post_id`, and a parent equal to the return value of the `blog_key()` method.

`blog_key()` is defined as:

```
def blog_key(name = 'default'):
return db.Key.from_path('blogs', name)
```

I'll be perfectly honest with you: I still haven't figured this part out (copied verbatim from [udacity cs253](https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-cs253/)) but I think what it's establishing is the ancestor value in the datastore for all `BlogPost` objects.

I've only been working with GAE for a couple weeks, working through the cs253 course, so I'd really appreciate any clarification on this, or a more clearly explained "what's happening"